# Lebesgue measure of the image of 2 functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We have the following [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107325/gammaa-b-to-mathbbrn-denote-by-gamma-gammatt-ina-b-imag?rq=1) where the Lebesgue measure of the image for a continuously differentiable function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ has Lebesgue measure zero. We denote the image of $f$ by $\Gamma_1$. Now suppose we have another function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that is also continuously differentiable whose image is denoted by $\Gamma_2$. We then know that $m(\Gamma_1)=m(\Gamma_2)=0$ (here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure).

Is it true that $m(\Gamma_1\cup \Gamma_2)=0$? In other words, if we plot the image of $f$ and $g$ on the same axis, is the Lebesgue measure of the two curves plotted together going to be zero?

I suspect that this cant be true as I thought you could have cases (in 2D for example) where your curves could produce some volume? However this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156907/help-with-a-proof-that-a-countable-union-of-measure-zero-sets-is-measure-zero) would say otherwise. I was hoping someone could bridge my understanding!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? $0\leq m(\Gamma_1\cup \Gamma_2)\leq m(\Gamma_1)+m(\Gamma_2)=0$.

Comment: Hi Feng! I see now. This is really helpful. This is actually super interesting. If I take countably many curves and plot their images in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then no `volume' will be created.